# Youtube API v3, getting a video from a uri

Tags: c#-4.0, youtube-api

So I have is the address:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P1EtSBxm0S4
what I want is the youTube.Data.V3.Video class (I think)

Back in the V2 api, you could do something like this and get a Video object for YouTube ID.

```
YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);
Uri uri = new Uri("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/P1EtSBxm0S4");
Google.YouTube.Video video = request.Retrieve<Video>(uri);
```

How do you do this in V3?  The examples don't seem to cover it.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe I should have been clearer that I am using the .NET API.  Looking at it from the classes the API offers, the examples are... not intuitive as to going about it. At least for me.
I think this is what I'm looking to do.

```
//you need to create the service object earlier
var request = youtubeService.Videos.List("snippet");

var EndOfURI = "P1EtSBxm0S4"; 
request.Id = EndOfURI; 
var response = request.Execute();          
if (response.Items.Count == 1) 
{            
    Video video = response.Items[0];        
    //video.Snippet has most of what you want
}
```

Comment: Note that there is `ExecuteAsync` method if you're looking for asynchronous variant. It can be awaited.

Comment: from where you got `youtubeService`?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the doc at https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list and use the 'Try It!' section at the bottom.

Your request should look like https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics&id=P1EtSBxm0S4&key=YOUR_API_KEY